# Set relative image size Paperclip [Rails]

Tags: paperclip

Is it posible to set a relative  size to a image with paperclip?
    Does exists something like this?

```
  :medium => "50x50%"
```

Answer (score 0):

see following links I think it would help you
watch resize option
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

and following link examples are there

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#percent

Thanks.